# disable ephemeral disk on azure vm with cloud-init

Tags: azure, packer, cloud-init

Ubuntu machines on azure got ephemeral disk that is being automatically mounted on `/mnt`

I don't want to have this ephemeral drive on `/mnt` but rather disable it or just move it to another location.

I'm using packer to create my base image on azure.

I've tried to achieve that with cloud-init like so:

```
mounts:
  - [/dev/sdb, null]
```

and also as with AWS:

```
mounts:
  - [ephemeral0, null]
```

but that didn't help, so I tried to edit `waagent.conf` and reboot the machine like so: 
`sed -i '/s/ResourceDisk.MountPoint=.*/ResourceDisk.MountPoint=\/ephemeral/' /etc/waagent.conf` 
but that didn't solve the issue either...

Ultimately I would like to solve it with cloud-init as I would like to mount another drive (persist data) on `/mnt` instead but any solution goes.

Thanks

Comment: why dont you mount the disk to any other path on the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu machines on azure support cloud-init,
hence it's very easy to create a simple file under `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/xyz.cfg` with some cloud-init commands.

In this case,
mount the ephemeral drive to a null point (or in other words - don't mount it).

```
cat << 'EOF' > /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/01-mounts.cfg
mounts:
  - [ ephemeral0, null ]
EOF
```

Comment: Hi! While this may be a solution to the question, code only answers are generally discouraged on SO. Please take some time to edit your response with an explanation as to why this is a solution as it will help OP and future visitors of the site.

Comment: @d_kennetz fair enough :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to completely override Azure's default mounts you have to override both ephemeral0 and ephemeral0.1.

This is working perfectly for Azure:

```
#cloud-config
mounts:
  - [ ephemeral0 ]
  - [ ephemeral0.1 ]
```

AWS uses configuration modules in a different order, and I was unable to define mount points for its' ephemeral NVME disks. If you're using non-NVME disks, maybe [BlockDeviceMapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-blockdev-mapping.html) for ephemerals will help you.

EDIT: In my experience, if you're using cloud-init you should disable waagent in order to avoid weird misconfigurations.